# Not Displaying All Elements Without Resizing the Window

Tags: java, user-interface

Okey, first, this is going to be an awkward question. Sorry about that.
I completed my project finally, but at the end, I'm facing with something frustrating.
My project is about 0's and 1's. The labels generating 0 or 1 randomly. It is 20 x 20 grid. 400 labels total.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class VHMP2 extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sum = 0;

    Random randomGen = new Random();

    String matrix[][] = new String[20][20];

    VHM1 frame = new VHM1();
    frame.setTitle("Homework 1");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 20));

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {

            int value = (int) (2 * Math.random());

            JLabel label = new JLabel();

            label.setFont(new Font("HueHue", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 10));
            label.setText("" + value);

            frame.add(p);
            p.add(label);

            if (value == 1) {
                sum++;
            }

        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sum = " + sum, "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}

}
```

This is my code so far. The problem is I can't see all numbers when I run the code(I can see only 6 of them). I have to resize the window to see all number. How can I solve this ? Thanks !

Comment: What's that supposed to mean ?

Comment: you have added component after set frame visible .so you need to repaint .or you can move frame.setvisible line after the end of the loop

Comment: Wow the solution is also awkward then :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The **setVisible(true);** part should be called after you added all other elements to the frame